# Is it possible to sort all php data into various divs by the day of week

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello im here with a problem, i want to retrieve data from mysql with php(done it :)) and then for example when my variable  `$dia_semana` is equal to sunday, it will show all the data with sunday into a especific div with a certain id, and then goes on

here is my php code:

```
<?php
function dia_da_semana() {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
    $sql ="SELECT temperature, humidity, data FROM sensor ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    setlocale(LC_TIME, "pt_PT"); // or LC_TIME

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo strftime("%A",$row['data']);
        echo "<h2>".$row['data']."</h2>";
        echo "<h4>".$row['temperature']."ºC</h4>";
        echo "<h4>".$row['humidity']."%</h4>";
    }
}

dia_da_semana();
?>
```

part of html code where i want it to be sent:

```
<div class="7days">

    <?php
        include "loadgraph.php"
    ?>
    <div class="day1">

    </div>
    <div class="day2">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is  'data' the same as 'date' in this context?

Comment: yes it is, sry im portuguese and usually mix both in ehe and data in mysql database is a datetime value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my code that fully works:

```
$WEEKDAYS = array(1 => "Sunday", 2 => "Monday", 3 => "Tuesday", 4 => "Wednesday", 5 => "Thursday", 6 => "Friday", 7 => "Saturday");
          $ResultsArray = array();

          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              // create an array to hold the return values from your DB
              $date = $row['dia_semana']; //<--- coming from db holds date values
              $ResultsArray[$date][] = $row['temperature'];
          }
            echo "<table style='padding:5px;border-radius: 10px;border:solid 1px #000;vertical-align: text-top;'>";
            echo "<tr>";

            foreach ($WEEKDAYS as $key => $date) {
              echo "<th>".$date."</th>";
            }
                echo "</tr>";
              for ($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++){

                  echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>".$ResultsArray['Sunday'][$x]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$ResultsArray['Monday'][$x]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$ResultsArray['Tuesday'][$x]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$ResultsArray['Wednesday'][$x]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$ResultsArray['Thursday'][$x]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$ResultsArray['Friday'][$x]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$ResultsArray['Saturday'][$x]."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
              }








          echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a constant/array to compare array with and set days of week to start at Sunday using key values. Then run foreach using that constant/array to echo out table data for each day that is present, beginning with Sunday. Check to see if the value in the constant is in your returned array and if it is, echo out that day and its corresponding values from the array that are also set to that day.

```
define("WEEKDAYS", [1 => "Sunday", 2 => "Monday", 3 => "Tuesday", 4 => "Wednesday", 5 => "Thursday", 6 => "Friday", 7 => "Saturday"]);

$parseDays = array(
    'Frank' => 'Monday',
    'Jean' => 'Monday',
    'Mike' => 'Sunday',
    'Bob' => 'Tuesday',
    'Bill' => 'Friday',
    'Jack' => 'Sunday',
    'George' => 'Friday',
    'Dillon' => 'Wednesday'
);
$stmt = '<table>';
$stmt .= '<tr>';
foreach(WEEKDAYS as $key => $day){
    if(in_array($day, $parseDays)){
        if($day === $day){
            $stmt .= '<td style="padding:5px;border-radius: 10px;border:solid 1px #000;vertical-align: text-top;">'.$day.'<hr>';
            foreach($parseDays as $name => $days){
                if($days === $day){
                    $stmt .= '<br>'.$name;
                }
            }
            $stmt .= '</td>';
        }
    }       
}
$stmt .= '</tr>';

$stmt .= '</div>';
echo $stmt;
```

IN YOUR CASE TRY THE FOLLOWING:

```
// make sure to define a constant that has the days to compare so we can start
// with Sunday and display in order of week from Sunday through the rest of 
// the week concurrently
define("WEEKDAYS", [1 => "Sunday", 2 => "Monday", 3 => "Tuesday", 4 => "Wednesday", 5 => "Thursday", 6 => "Friday", 7 => "Saturday"]);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    // create an array to hold the return values from your DB
    $date[] = $row['dia_semana']; //<--- coming from db holds date values
}

// construct the table and display the days
$stmt = '<table>';
$stmt .= '<tr>';
//loop through the constant and get the days in order from Sunday concurrently
foreach(WEEKDAYS as $key => $day){
    // check if the $day value from constant is located in the $date array from db
    if(in_array($day, $date)){
        if($day === $day){
            $stmt .= '<td style="padding:5px;border-radius: 10px;border:solid 1px #000;vertical-align: text-top;">'.$day.'<hr>';
            // loop through db array and assign key/values
            foreach($date as $name => $days){
                // If value from db array is equal to value from constant, display it
                if($days === $day){
                    $stmt .= '<br>'. //enter name values here;
                }
            }
            $stmt .= '</td>';
        }
    }       
}
$stmt .= '</tr>';

$stmt .= '</div>';
echo $stmt;
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: oh what the hell.... i will give it a try and give you a fedback on it much apreciated

Comment: You can set the properties in your while loop coming from the DB or after assigning the row values run that through a foreach loop and compare values as I did with an array that allows you to set first day as you wish on Sunday.

Comment: hey im trying to insert this code in mine, but there is some variables that i just cant figure where i should use them

Comment: and is it supposed to have that `</div>` in last code lines

Comment: will $row[] contain the key 'days' that holds the value from DB -> `$row['days']`? How exactly are looking to display this info as is you can wrap your while loop around the $row['days'] and then see if certain days are set and display them.  `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { if($row['days'] === 'Sunday'){ //compare $row array with set weekday array and display if conditions match as I did in my example. }`

Comment: $row will contain the values from data, temperature and humidity

Comment: where do the days you wish to compare and display come from?

Comment: come from the database which the variable name is called data and i used the DAYNAME() to extract the day of week from data

Comment: and the name of that array would be? is it $row['data']? So the return value of  `DAYNAME($row['data'])` = for ex. `Sunday`

Comment: no i do the `SELECT .... DAYNAME(data) as dia_semana` and then i just call it inside the while loop like this `echo "<h2>".$row['dia_semana']."</h2>";`

Comment: okay i see $row['dia_semana'] holds the day value... See my updated answer

Comment: ok now i understand what you doing is the path i was taking too put it doesnt show me nothing

Comment: When you add the data from db to array `$date` var_dump this and trouble shoot, do you get results that show the data from DB with dates?

Comment: i used `var_dump($date);` still nothing smh just trying to figure it out, just a thing is that las div supposed to be there or is it supposed to be a `</table>`

Comment: and i still couldnt figure it out... even the graph i had in the website dissapeared, doesnt show anything, but i dont see where is the problem XD

Comment: ok the graph appeared again just need to figure where the hell is the problem that the table with the collumns dont appear smh XD

Comment: yea i used the `var_dump` and shows all the days like thursday and sunday, but doesnt show in the table smhXD

Comment: hey bro, is eberything alright with you? getting a bit worried over here

Comment: Can you update your code with what you have now please?

Comment: heyyy wassup bro, i can now show everything! i made it thanks for your help i mixed your code with a sprinkle of mine